# Establish a relationship between tow columns were one column has duplicate data

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The below dataset was imported to Neo4j. I need to establish a relationship indicating that Table_ID contains the data in Column_ID.

```
Table_ID    Table       Column_ID   Column
8       Product     1753        Key
8       Product     1754        Lock
8       Product     1755        Switch
8       Product     1756        Bolt
9       Catalogue   1761        Key
9       Catalogue   1762        Wrench
9       Catalogue   1763        Spanner
9       Catalogue   1764        Screw
9       Catalogue   1765        Bolt
```

To create a relationship indicating the Table_Id contains the Column_id.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:Column_ID) ASSERT c.id IS UNIQUE;

CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (t:Table_ID) ASSERT t.id IS UNIQUE;

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Tableid_ColumnID.csv" AS line

MATCH (c:Column {id: toInteger (line.Column_ID)}) 

MATCH (t:Table {id: toInteger (line.Table_ID)})

MERGE (t)-[:CONTAINS]->(c)
```

The query returned with (no changes, no records). Could someone help on this query, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. By default `LOAD CSV` uses a comma as the data separator. Your data file is using one or 2 tabs as the separator. So, use this data, instead:

   ```
   Table_ID,Table,Column_ID,Column
   8,Product,1753,Key
   8,Product,1754,Lock
   8,Product,1755,Switch
   8,Product,1756,Bolt
   9,Catalogue,1761,Key
   9,Catalogue,1762,Wrench
   9,Catalogue,1763,Spanner
   9,Catalogue,1764,Screw
   9,Catalogue,1765,Bolt
   ```
2. You did not show how you created the initial nodes, so here is an example of how to do that (note that the node labels are `Column` and `Table`, NOT `Column_ID` and `Table_ID`) using your csv file:

   ```
   LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Tableid_ColumnID.csv" AS line
   MERGE (c:Column {id: TOINTEGER(line.Column_ID)})
   ON CREATE SET c.name = line.Column
   MERGE (t:Table {id: TOINTEGER(line.Table_ID)})
   ON CREATE SET t.name = line.Table
   ```
3. Given the above node labels, your constraints were not created correctly, since you do not have any nodes with the `Column_ID` and `Table_ID` labels. Here are the corrected statements:

   ```
   CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:Column) ASSERT c.id IS UNIQUE;

   CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (t:Table) ASSERT t.id IS UNIQUE;
   ```
4. With the above fixes, your query (repeated below) will now work as expected:

   ```
   LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Tableid_ColumnID.csv" AS line
   MATCH (c:Column {id: TOINTEGER(line.Column_ID)}) 
   MATCH (t:Table {id: TOINTEGER(line.Table_ID)})
   MERGE (t)-[:CONTAINS]->(c)
   ```

Comment: Thank you @cybersam for the detailed steps. I did not have the command ' ON CREATE SET c.name=line.Column' and 'ON CREATE SET t.name=line.Table' in my script to create the initial set of nodes. I updated the query and corrected the constraints query as explained and it created the graph correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This would indicate that either one of the matches failed (so either the :Column and :Table nodes weren't imported properly or at all prior to this, or the spelling and/or case of the labels and properties doesn't match to what was actually imported), or that the relationship you're trying to MERGE already exists between all of the matched nodes.

You may want to either run a PROFILE of the query (which should be safe since nothing in the graph was modified as a result) and ensure that the matches resulted in rows and that a non-zero number of rows were present at the point where the relationship was being merged, or check for yourself for some limited number of rows from the CSV that the matches to `c` and `t` are actually succeeding (LIMIT line, keep the matches and return them, avoiding the merge).

That should tell you if the problem is on the matches, or if the merge simply matched to existing relationships (meaning this import was already performed previously).